# calculated value of a var does not affect in pie chart in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

Here you will find this code that caculates two values, which are **memorizeNum** and **notMemorizeNum**

```
    getWordLength();
    var memorizeNum = 0;
    var notMemorizeNum = 0;
    const getWordLength = () => {
        
        data.map((item)=>{
            
            if (item.user_word.memorize === true) {
                memorizeNum = memorizeNum + 1
            }
            if (item.user_word.memorize === false) {
                notMemorizeNum = notMemorizeNum + 1
            }
            
        })
        console.log(memorizeNum) ----- gives 2
        console.log(notMemorizeNum) ---- gives 4
    }
```

According to the two console.log, these will give two numbers, which are **2** and **4**. These values should be put in a pie chart. This is the code of Rechart library.

```
 return (

        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%"  >
            <PieChart width={400} height={400}>
                <Pie
                    dataKey="value"
                    isAnimationActive={false}
                    data={[{ id: "finish", value: memorizeNum }, { id: "notFinish", value: notMemorizeNum }]}
                    cx="50%"
                    cy="50%"
                    outerRadius={80}
                    fill="#8884d8"
                    label
                />
                <Tooltip />
            </PieChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>

    )
```

The two values of var decide the shape of the pie, however, I found that the initial value is entered **regardless of the calculated variable value**. So, if I set the initial value

```
var memorizeNum = 3;
var notMemorizeNum = 3;
```

The pie chart displays the shape of the circle, which is cut in half.

Could you please tell me the reason and how do I input the value of the calculated variable?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: nope. on webpage, it just gives piechart consist of initial value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is, you are storing the values in variables which are not state variables and react doesn't monitor changes of those variables and re-render when their value change.

So create 2 individual state states or one state object like:

```
const [chartData,setChartData] = useState({memorizeNum: 0, notMemorizeNum : 0});
```

and then set it under the calculation logic with new data like:

```
setChartData({ New data here });
```

and then pass this data to your chart like:

```
data={[{ id: "finish", value: chartData.memorizeNum }, { id: "notFinish", value: chartData.notMemorizeNum }]}
```

and it will work.